# Getting nan loss values during ANN regression training

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I am quite new to machine learning, python and pytorch.
I am working on a project related to ANN regression. Just to test my understanding, I am trying to use some columns of Dataset ( 13 columns) and trying to run a very basic circuit of ANN. Below are details of input and output after data preprocessing:

My input is :

```
conts_total[:5]

tensor([[ 1.0000, 13.0000,  8.0000,  7.0000,  7.0000,  0.3171,  0.4800,  0.0000,
          0.0000,  0.0000,  0.1148,  1.0000,  0.0000],
        [ 3.0000, 16.0000,  8.0000,  3.0000,  9.0000,  0.4634,  0.4200,  0.0000,
          0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0820,  0.0000,  1.0000],
        [ 4.0000,  4.0000,  5.0000, 11.0000, 11.0000,  0.6829,  0.4400,  0.0000,
          0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0656,  0.0000,  0.0000],
        [ 5.0000, 13.0000,  4.0000, 17.0000, 17.0000,  0.6829,  0.5800,  0.0000,
          0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  1.0000],
        [ 7.0000, 11.0000,  5.0000, 10.0000, 10.0000,  0.7317,  0.7000,  0.0000,
          0.0000,  0.0000,  0.2623,  2.0000,  0.0000]])

conts_total.shape
torch.Size([20453, 13])
```

The output is:

```
y[:5]
tensor([[7.0000],
        [6.5000],
        [8.5000],
        [8.0000],
        [3.5000]])
y.shape
torch.Size([20453, 1])
```

The very basic model I am using is :

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,in_features, h1, h2,out_features):
         # How many layers ?
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features, h1)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(h1, h2)
        self.out = nn.Linear(h2,out_features)
        

    def forward(self,x):
       
       
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.out(x)

        return x

torch.manual_seed(32)
model = Model(in_features=13, h1= 64, h2= 32, out_features=1)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr =0.001)

for epoch in range(100):
    optimizer.zero_grad()  # Clear the gradients from the previous iteration
    output = model(conts_total)  # Forward pass
    loss = criterion(output, y)  # Calculate the loss
    loss.backward()  # Backward pass
    optimizer.step()  # Update the weights

    if epoch % 10 == 0:
        print(f"Epoch {epoch}, Loss {loss.item():.4f}")
```

After doing everything, I am getting `nan` values as loss. I would be a greatest help if someone guide me how to correct this very basic model.
Thank you in advance.

**Edit**

I tried printing the values in between. Looking at the printed values, the model is not at all working and everything is nan as shown below:

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,in_features, h1, h2,out_features):
         # How many layers ?
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features, h1)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(h1, h2)
        self.out = nn.Linear(h2,out_features)
        

    def forward(self,x):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.out(x)
        print('Flag4:', x)
        return x

Flag 4: tensor([[-2.4338e-01],
    [-2.0514e-01],
    [-3.1053e-01],
    ...,
    [-1.0478e+03],
    [-1.0481e+03],
    [-1.0481e+03]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward0>)<ReluBackward0>)
```

Please suggest a way to correct these errors.

Comment: You should normalize your data.

Comment: Thank you @Ivan for the response. Is there a way to normalize 'conts_total' and  'y' with some pytorch API?

Comment: First try normalizing the input: `(counts_total-counts_total.min())/(counts_total.max()-counts_total.min())`

Comment: @Ivan I tried your normalize formula, but still getting nan.

Comment: When do you get Nan, is it on the very first iteration or after a few iterations?

Comment: @Ivan The formula is basically not normalizing the input. It produces a matrix with all elements nan. Need some edit in the formula. It is always a nan from the start.

Comment: Hi @Ivan, I edited the question to make problem more clear.

Comment: This means you have nan in your array to start with!!!

Comment: @Ivan I have edited the question. If i send unormalized counts_total, and take a print just before the return in the forward function of the model, I am getting the values.

Comment: Yes, the reason this happens is that you have at least one nan value in your tensor. ***Please check that this is indeed the case.*** You can do so with [`torch.isnan`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.isnan.html) applied on your tensor (forget about normalization ofc).

Comment: Yes, my data is bad containing Nan Values. Thank you @Ivan for this great and kind help. Your solution for checking nan i.e, torch.isnan helped in detecting the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Cross entropy loss is almost exclusively used in classification problems. The loss function is incorrect here. Although normalizing should work but you have to normalize both inputs and outputs between [0,1]. Since y is not a probability I would say using CEL here is imprecise. **Try using MSE or L1Loss().**

You can read more about it online but tl;dr it assumes that the output of the model and y is between [0, 1]. If the p(i) is > 1 the term log(p(i)) is positive and the whole term becomes negative, i.e. negative loss. If p(i) is <= 0, well log is not defined for that, and hence the nan. The gradients are not defined for nan loss.

Comment: Thank you @PushkarJajoria for the response. I am finding problem in calculating normalization.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please review the edits. I think, the only problem is the normalization of input and output values.

Comment: As I said before, the loss function/criterion is incorrect. You cannot use Cross Entropy loss for a regression problem. Use MeanSquaredError and try training the model and it should work.

Normalization is a good practice in machine learning and you should do that whenever possible, but that is not the issue here. There are many resources available only on normalizing data in python, remember to normalize both X and Y. Also remember to normalize your training and test set together and not separately.