# Normalizing an input and output tensors giving Nan Result

Tags: python, pytorch

I am new python, pytorch and machine learning.I am trying to understand ANN example with my dataset.
I am trying to normalize the input and output tensor.
My input tensor is :

```
conts_total[:5]
tensor([[ 1.0000, 13.0000,  8.0000,  7.0000,  7.0000,  0.3171,  0.4800,  0.0000,
          0.0000,  0.0000,  0.1148,  1.0000,  0.0000],
        [ 3.0000, 16.0000,  8.0000,  3.0000,  9.0000,  0.4634,  0.4200,  0.0000,
          0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0820,  0.0000,  1.0000],
        [ 4.0000,  4.0000,  5.0000, 11.0000, 11.0000,  0.6829,  0.4400,  0.0000,
          0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0656,  0.0000,  0.0000],
        [ 5.0000, 13.0000,  4.0000, 17.0000, 17.0000,  0.6829,  0.5800,  0.0000,
          0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  1.0000],
        [ 7.0000, 11.0000,  5.0000, 10.0000, 10.0000,  0.7317,  0.7000,  0.0000,
          0.0000,  0.0000,  0.2623,  2.0000,  0.0000]])
```

The shape of the input tensor is:

```
conts_total.shape
torch.Size([20453, 13])
```

When I normalize the conts_total using the below formula:

```
model_input = (conts_total-conts_total.min())/(conts_total.max()-conts_total.min())
model_input[:5]
```

The result I  get it as follows:

```
tensor([[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]])
```

It would be great help if someone can guide with normalization.

** Edit **

```
conts_total.min()
tensor(nan)

conts_total.max()
tensor(nan)
```

Comment: You may want to check `conts_total.min()` and `conts_total.max()`.

Comment: Thank you @tevemadar for the response. I have edited the question. Both of these values are coming out as nan. Is there any other formula you can suggest?

Comment: This bug may be the one you see: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/25016 - however it's supposedly fixed for 3+ years by now.

Comment: @tevemadar Any other way to resolve this problem. My normalization problem is related to my this  problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75852978/getting-nan-loss-values-during-ann-regression-training?noredirect=1#comment133805134_75852978

Comment: You are getting confused, I mentioned in your other thread why this happened. You have a tensor that most probably has nan values. If you normalize your data, you will turn all your data into nan because your `torch.min` and `torch.max` calls both return `nan`.

Comment: Yes, my data is bad containing Nan Values. Thank you @Ivan for this great and kind help. Your solution for checking nan i.e, torch.isnan  resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

High probability that the input data itself has some nans, please check using:

```
torch.isnan(tensor_name).any()
```

Comment: I asked this question a long time back. The problem was with the data. There were a lot of nan values in the data, which took me a lot of time to understand.